# Flutter fromJson - Unhandled error Unhandled error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' occurred in Instance of

Tags: json, flutter, bloc

I'm using HydratedBloc to try to store color to json as an int value so I don't have a massive if/else method that does a bunch of `if (color == Colors.blue) => 'blue'` etc...

So I'm trying this:

```
 int mapColorToInt(Color color) => color.value;

 Color mapIntToColor(int colorValue) => Color(colorValue);

  @override
  ThemeState fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NewTheme(
      themeData: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: mapIntToColor(json['scaffoldBackgroundColor']),
        accentColor: mapIntToColor(json['accentColor']),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(ThemeState state) {
    return {
      'scaffoldBackgroundColor':
          mapColorToInt(state.themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor),
      'accentColor': mapColorToInt(state.themeData.accentColor),
    };
  }
```

And get this error:

Unhandled error Unhandled error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' occurred in Instance of 'ThemeBloc'.

Which I don't understand if integer is a supported type, but based on my search it seems I'm not the only one to have issues with integers and json.

So then I tried doing the same thing but keeping it all strings:

```
 String mapColorToInt(Color color) => color.value.toString();

 Color mapIntToColor(String colorValue) => Color(int.parse(colorValue));

  @override
  ThemeState fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return NewTheme(
      themeData: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: mapIntToColor(json['scaffoldBackgroundColor']),
        accentColor: mapIntToColor(json['accentColor']),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(ThemeState state) {
    return {
      'scaffoldBackgroundColor':
          mapColorToInt(state.themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor),
      'accentColor': mapColorToInt(state.themeData.accentColor),
    };
  }
```

And that gives this error:

Unhandled error Unhandled error FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)

Clearly I'm missing something here but its not clear what. I tested the mapIntToColor function in the UI and it works fine when passed a `color.value`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know json['accentColor']'s example.

 
If that json value is like '#FCFDSD', try using below code.

```
scaffoldBackgroundColor: HexColor(json['scaffoldBackgroundColor']),
```

```
class HexColor extends Color {
  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll('#', '');
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = 'FF' + hexColor;
    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }

  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

Comment: Hi Kuku, thanks for the response. The .value on a color is different from the hex value but I still tried your code using hex values and got the invalid radix error unfortunately.

Comment: let me know your json's color value?

Comment: Ok so if I pass in Colors.blue to my mapColorToInt function, it returns 4280391411. According to the docs the value property is a 32 bit value representing the color.

Comment: Would you print 'state.themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor' value and 'state.themeData.accentColor'?

Comment: state.themeData.scaffoldBackgroundColor' prints:  MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xff2196f3))

Comment: state.themeData.accentColor prints: MaterialColor(primary value: Color(0xffffeb3b))